# Angular material date picker return Moment object instead of Date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a strange problem, in my html I defined-

```
    <mat-radio-button value="embargoed">
        <div>Everyone, limited by date</div>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="data.selected === 'embargoed'">
            <mat-label>Available from date</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" #input [(ngModel)]="date">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-radio-button>
```

in my comonent I initialized-

```
date = new Date();
```

I have an OnSubmit function that does-

```
onSubmit(){
    if (this.data.selected === 'embargoed') {
        this.data.date = this.date;
    }
}
```

In debud I can see that this.date is a Moment object instead of a Date object, any idea why?

Comment: have you provided MAT_DATE_FORMATS with MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS?

Comment: Yes, I just realized it! but I had to do it inorder to format my dates.

Comment: I wanted to use local 'en-GB' and according to the angular-material this is the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason. In my `app.module.ts` I had declared:

```
 {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview:

> The type of values that the datepicker expects depends on the type of DateAdapter provided in your application. The NativeDateAdapter, for example, works directly with plain JavaScript Date objects. When using the MomentDateAdapter, however, the values will all be Moment.js instances.

Also: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings:

> The datepicker was built to be date implementation agnostic. This means that it can be made to work with a variety of different date implementations. However it also means that developers need to make sure to provide the appropriate pieces for the datepicker to work with their chosen implementation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32240723)

Answer (score -1):

```
this.date = new Date(this.date);
```

Comment: You should provide some details of your solution. Posts including just a code snippet are usually not self-explanatory.